# How to fix node position and increase edge spacing in Pyvis network graph?

Tags: python, charts, networkx, pyvis

I am very new to Python and its graph libraries however i have a requirement to construct a directed graph network with multiple nodes and edges. I have kind of achieved the functionality but with a couple of hiccups. One, unable to fix the position of the nodes in the network i.e it changes with every refresh and secondly, the edges between two nodes kind of overlap. How can I fix these two issues? code snippets are given below

```
net = Network('500px','100%',notebook=True,
              cdn_resources="remote",
              bgcolor="#white",
              font_color="black",
              select_menu=True,
              directed=True,
              neighborhood_highlight=True
              )
net.add_node(AppName, label=AppName, title=AppDetails, shape="oval", color=#222234)
net.add_edge(IntSource, IntTarget, label=IntFriceId, title=IntName, color=#555676, arrows='to')
```

Comment: You can provide `x` and `y` coordinates when creating nodes and disable physics for them.

Comment: Mentioning x and y coordinates does work but it seems to lead to another issue, now on clicking any node alters the graph topology, behaves like a water bubble. Without the x, y coordinates the nodes behave properly on clicking I.e they get highlighted.

Comment: Perhaps if you might want to disable physics altogether. It is hard to tell with no functional example